# Word 2013 VBA Type mismatch error when calling from Field

Tags: vba, call, ms-word, type-mismatch

I haven't coded in some time, and then it wasn't Visual Basic so forgive me if my question is simple or poorly explained.

I have a Sub CustomSave() which verifies that there aren't blank ContentControls where they need to be filled in, then SaveAs's the (.docm) Word document with a title of "User Name" "Date Requested" "Requested Action" then deletes { Save } (see below) and 1 other Field in the document to prevent unintentional editing.

The Sub runs perfectly when I Run it from VBA.

The Sub is called (without passing anything) from a Field:
`{MacroButton CustomSave Save}`

When I activate said field, I get this error:
(Title) Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications [X]
(Content) Type mismatch
(Options) [OK][Help]

Help just takes me to the generic Microsoft online help that I couldn't find the answer.

I'm retyping the code, so disregard the lack of a save directory and please don't assume typos exist in the actual document if I make a mistake here:

```
Sub CustomSave()

' Deselect the Save Field   
Selection.Collapse

' Set checks for required data
Dim tRequest As Boolean
Dim tUser As Boolean
Dim tOffice As Boolean
Dim tCard As Boolean
tRequest = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Request").Item(1).ShowingPlaceholderText
tUser = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("User").Item(1).ShowingPlaceholde    tText
tOffice = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Office").Item(1).ShowingPlaceholderText
tCard = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Card").Item(1).ShowingPlaceholderText

' Set file name variables
Dim cardHolder As String
Dim cardAction As String
cardHolder = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("User")(1).Range.Text
cardAction = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Request")(1).Range.Text

' Check all and Error out if missing required data
If tRequest Then
    Msg = "Action Requested is required."
    MsgBox = Msg,,"Error"
    Exit Sub

ElseIf tUser Then
    Msg = "Username is required."
    MsgBox = Msg,,"Error"
    Exit Sub

ElseIf ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Request")(1).Range.Text = "New" Then
    ' Embedded If to check fields only required for new requests

    If tCard Then
        Msg = "Card type is required."
        MsgBox = Msg,,"Error"
        Exit Sub

    ElseIf tOffice Then
        Msg = "Office location is required."
        MsgBox = Msg,,"Error"
        Exit Sub

    Else
        GoTo Save

    End If

'If all checks are satisfied, save to the designated location
Else
Save:
    ' Remove the Save and Clear Fields but not the first Field
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        With rng.Fields
            While .Count > 1
                .Item(2).Delete
            Wend
        End With
    Next

    ' Finally, perform the save
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 ("Dir" & cardHolder & " " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & cardAction & ".docm")

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: post the sub's code.

Comment: @cyboashu updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I caused the error by having the code in two places- under the ThisDocument Object and the Macros Module. I deleted the ThisDocument version and the script runs.